# Backbone.js & Node.js: Looking for a best practice for application settings

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, configuration, settings

I'm building a web application based on backbone.js as the frontend and node.js as the backend.

I am looking for best practices on loading and saving the application settings/configuration a backbone/node environment. The idea is to allow an admin user to view/edit the settings, and of course these settings will silently be loaded when any user is accessing the application through the web.

I was thinking of creating a backbone model called 'settings', which will be loaded once the application starts. Then add a settings view where admins can view and edit at will. Not all the settings will be pre-loaded, only when the admin tried to access them (for eg. settings that are relevant for the backend will only be shown in the admin edit page, and not pre-loaded on application start)

Note: These settings will be saved in a MongoDB document.

How do you guys manage your web application settings/configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any data that is going to be accessible through the client and retrieved from your database should be represented by a backbone model. Your intuition of creating a 'settings' backbone model will allow you to display the data retrieved from your MongoDB backend. Then, when the settings are updated in your view, you can save the backbone model, which will in turn update the settings in your db.

Since you are dealing with settings/configurations that can affect your application, you just want to make sure that you do correct validation on anyone trying to access that specific page.

Comment: Appreciate your response. So I went for a single document stored on mongo, which backbone can query at will. Thanks!